# "Add comment" button overflowing

Tags: bug, design

I was leaving a comment on an accepted answer, and I noticed that the "add comment" button was overflowing, as was some of the text of the comments.

[image]

This appears on several other threads ([one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278720/can-only-the-constructible-sets-be-proven-to-exist-in-zf-without-benefit-of-ex), [two](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282013/towers-of-induced-functions), [three](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11633/is-it-possible-for-countably-closed-forcing-to-collapse-aleph-2-to-aleph-1) examples), but not on others. And I could not find any patterns which fits the whole thing (e.g. some MathJax causing breakage).

(I am using Chromium 61.0.3163.100 on Arch Linux 64bit, any additional technical details will be added on demand.)

---

(Added after Stefan Kohl's comment)

Using Firefox there is no text of button overflow, but it is clear that something is wrong:

[image]

---

Here is a screen shot from Firefox on Android (Nexus 6p) in "full site" mode, while there is no overflow (even the separating lines), something is obviously wrong,for example the separator lines reach all the way to the end of the colored region, while before the add comment dialog is open, they don't.

[image]

Comment: I am using the recent Firefox, and for me no comment text and no [Add Comment] button appears to be overflowing. Additionally, it seems that for me more characters fit into one line -- e.g. I see the first line break in the comment you give as an example after "thread.". All text is well within the green box. When I click [Add a comment|, the line break moves after the "At", but still nothing traverses the right side of the green box.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Do you happen to have Chrome or Chromium installed for testing? I will try Firefox on my end as well.

Comment: No, I have no other browser installed for testing.

Comment: In Firefox, also the font used for the comments looks a tiny bit different.

Comment: There is usually some difference between browsers. I posted a screenshot with my Firefox.

Comment: Your Firefox screenshot is almost exactly what I see (up to the "to" in your comment, which I see on the next line).

Comment: So the separating lines *are* overflowing? And the text does reach too close to the edge of the colored region?

Comment: Yes, the text reaches quite close to the edge of the colored region. It would look better if it woudn't, but is it a bug? Which separating lines do you mean?

Comment: There are horizontal lines between different comments. I mean those.